# Angular 2 - Form submission not retrieving the value property

Tags: javascript, forms, angular, typescript, angular-forms

I am new to angular2 and learning. The following code does not output `f.value` to the console. It returns an empty object. Am I missing something here. I am using rc4.

any help will be great.

**component.ts**

```typescript
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { NgForm} from '@angular/forms';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'fa-template-driven-form',
  templateUrl: 'template-driven-form.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['template-driven-form.component.css']
})
export class TemplateDrivenFormComponent {

  onSubmit(form:NgForm) {
    console.log(form); // results in {}
  }

}
```

**template-driven-form.component.html**

```html
<h1>Template Driven form</h1>
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" #f="ngForm">
  <div class="field">
    <label for="username">UserName</label>
    <input type="text" name="username" id="username" ngModel>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="email">Email</label>
    <input type="email" name="email" id="email" ngModel>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <label for="password">Password</label>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="password" ngModel>
  </div>
  <div class="field">
    <button type="submit">Sign up</button>
  </div>
</form>
```

**package.json**

```
{   
   "@angular/common": "2.0.0-rc.4",
   "@angular/compiler": "2.0.0-rc.4",
   "@angular/core": "2.0.0-rc.4",
   "@angular/forms": "0.2.0",
   "@angular/http": "2.0.0-rc.4",
   "@angular/platform-browser": "2.0.0-rc.4",
   "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "2.0.0-rc.4",
   "@angular/router": "3.0.0-beta.2", 
}
```

Comment: This is a great video on Angular 2 Forms and the difference between model and  template driven versions - well worth a watch for learning purposes https://youtu.be/E92KS_YCSf8

Comment: Thanks. I ll take a look

Answer (score 1):

It should be "onSubmit(f.value)".